# Are connected UDP sockets widely used?

Tags: sockets

I am learning about sockets in C, and I just learned that you can connect an UDP socket (and its consequences) through [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=functions-connect) piece of documentation from IBM.
My question is: How popular are UDP connected sockets nowadays, and what could be an example of its usage over unconnected UDP sockets?

Comment: They are exactly the same sockets, just using different function calls

Comment: From the documentation I was assuming unconnected UDP sockets differ from connected ones so that once you connect them you can only send UDP packets to the address you connected it to, whereas the other one can still be used to send them to any address. I was wondering what real-world applications do these two functionalities have.

Comment: It's hard to know what counts as "widely used", but I will say that I avoid calling `connect()` on UDP sockets in my code.  The only benefit of using `connect()` on a UDP socket is that afterwards you can call `send()` and `recv()` on the UDP socket rather than `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`, which is only a minor convenience.  The big downside (IMO) of calling `connect()` is that it renders the UDP socket incapable of receiving UDP packets from any other source-address/port than the exact one specified in the `connect()` call; that's often a problem, especially when using IPv6/fe80 addressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are essentially the same sockets, just accessed with different function calls. If you only intend to communicate with one address, then you might find it more convenient to use a connected socket, so that you don't need to give the address to each send call, and you don't need to check the address when receiving.